# Is it possible to get/set environment variable with ng.probe?

Tags: angular, debugging

I've been using `ng.probe` to change settings durring the runtime of my Angular application.

Now one thing that I want to do, is change a environment variable without rebuilding the whole application, is this possible with `ng.probe` ?

Comment: From what I can tell `ng.probe` only allows access to a debug element dom tree.  As far as I have seen there is no way to change environment variables while it is already running, as thats not typically something that a browser has access.

I think you need to provide more information as to what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to change environment (Staging, Production, Test, etc) without having to rebuild the application.

I could do this with a proxy or changing the application code to fetch these URL from somewhere dynamic, but I was wondering if it was possible with `ng.probe`